# Legal Proceedings concerning one individual due as a defendant in two courts at the same time

Tags: united-kingdom, process, multiple-jurisdiction

A person is due to be a defendant in a court case in county 1, but they get arrested for another crime the night before their trial in county 2, meaning they are due in two court rooms at the same time, how is the situation rectified?

Comment: Is the [tag:civil-procedure] tag appropriate for this question if there were arrests involved? If two countries were involved perhaps the [tag:international] tag would apply along with [tag:criminal-procedure]?

Comment: @JasonAller: Two *counties*, not countries. If counties work in the UK as they do in VA, each county has its own courts.

Comment: @cHao that certainly simplifies things.